# Get the difference between two arrays in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

The `$category` variable will either hold values (i.e. tags) that are already available in the `tags` table, or the user can enter new tags in this variable , or both.

Following is the query that brings tags if they are available in the `tags` table:

```php
$TagNames = DB::table('tags')
                    ->whereIn('t_name', $category)                  
                    ->pluck('t_name');
```

The output of TagNames :

```php
array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "Zamalek" [1]=> string(4) "Ahly" }
```

Below is the `$category` variable that will hold all the tags, regardless they are new tags entered by  the user, or existing ones.

```php
$category = $request->get('catBox');
```

Output of `$category` (with two additional new tags) :

```php
array(4) { [0]=> string(7) "Zamalek" [1]=> string(4) "Ahly" [2]=> string(5) "Gouna" [3]=> string(8) "Pyramids" }
```

The question is : How can I compare both `arrays` and get only the difference (i.e. "Gouna" and "pyramids" in this case) in a new array ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need to retrieve only the differences from the $category.

You can use PHP inbuild function [array_diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) function.

```
$differenceArray = array_diff($category, $TagNames);
```

Keep in mind that, it will not display the difference of $TagNames.

To retrieve all the difference, you can retrieve the first difference and second difference and use [array_merge()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function to merge it together.

```
$differenceArray1 = array_diff($category, $TagNames);
$differenceArray2 = array_diff($TagNames, $category);

$mergeDifference = array_merge($differenceArray1, $differenceArray2);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use array_diff(A,B), it returns all elements from A, which are not elements of B (= A without B).

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
?>
```

Output of difference array1 from array2 is in this output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => blue
)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use php function named array_diff and it will return you non matching items by comparing values.

```
<?php
    $array1 = array(0=> 'Language', 1=>'Math', 2=>'Science', 3=>'Geography');
    $array2 = array(0=> 'Math', 1=>'Science', 2=>'History');
    $diff_result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
    print_r($diff_result);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Language [3] => Geography)
```

Ref: https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/array_diff.php

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Laravel way, for those that want to stick with Laravel helpers instead of array_diff for whatever reason.

Let's say you have collection 1 called `$activeUserIds` and collection 2 called `$allUserIds` and you want to find the inactive users IDs...

`$inactiveUserIds = $activeUserIds->diff($allUserIds);`